# Count Total In Database

Tags: mysql

I would like to have user can see where are they come and how many comment and make total group by country:

Is this correct?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

  function drawRegionsMap() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', 'Politics'],
      <?php 
      $sql = mysql_query("SELECT country FROM comments WHERE userid = '$userid' AND GROUP BY country");
      $output = "";
      $countpeople = mysql_num_rows($sql); 
      while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
          }
        echo $output;
      ?>
    ]);

    var options = {'backgroundColor': '#E9F6FD'};

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
};
</script>
```

Is there a way to make SELECT SUM?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: This question is not very precise, so my answer is also a not so precise “yes, MySQL can SUM().” – http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum

Comment: And please, stop concatenating values into the SQL, please use query binding ALWAYS, it prevents a number of problems, starting with SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it by modifying query

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT sum(country) as total FROM comments WHERE userid = '$userid' AND GROUP BY country");
```

And you can get out put in

```
echo $row['total']
```

Comment: Summing up countries? UK + USA = ?

Comment: @sumit joshi : Thanks for the fast prompt. I just make a change, but still no result output on the geochart.

Comment: @tombom : What does you means?

Comment: I mean that this query does not work at all. `country` is most likely text? Even if it's not, it doesn't make sense to sum up countries. Also he is grouping by country, therefore summing country does make even less sense, if that's even possible.

Answer (score 1):

Of all the code posted, only the query is relevant to this question, and the query you need is thus:

```
SELECT country, count(*) as total
FROM comments
WHERE userid = '$userid'
GROUP BY country
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I just make some change, but still no result output on the chart. Should I open another question? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, open a new question. You've solved the data aspect, now you have a rendering problem.

Comment: I have posted on new question, have a look on that please.